# What is the antonym of encapsulation?

Tags: oop, unit-testing, terminology, encapsulation

Using [online dictionary tools](http://encarta.msn.com/thesaurus_561572459/encapsulate.html) doesn't really help.  I think the way encapsulate is use in computer science doesn't exactly match its meaning in plain English.

What is the antonym of computer science's version of encaspulate?  More specifically, what is an antonym for encapsulate that would work as a function name.

---

Why should I care?  Here's my motivation:

```
// A class with a private member variable;
class Private
{
public:
   // Test will be able to access Private's private members;
   class Test;
private:
   int i;
}

// Make Test exactly like Private
class Private::Test : public Private
{
public:
   // Make Private's copy of i available publicly in Test
   using Private::i;
};

// A convenience function to quickly break encapsulation on a class to be tested.
// I don't have good name for what it does
Private::Test& foo( Private& p )
{ return *reinterpret_cast<Private::Test*>(&p); } // power cast

void unit_test()
{
   Private p;
   // using the function quickly grab access to p's internals.
   // obviously it would be evil to use this anywhere except in unit tests.
   assert( foo(p).i == 42 );
}
```

Comment: First you need to answer the question: _what_ is encapsulated? Then if you say something specific, then you can reverse the operation by, say, making it public or accessible which is something like publishing it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The antonym is "C".

Ok, just kidding. (Sort of.)

The best terms I can come up with are "expose" and "violate".

Comment: 'expose' is great and it's short.  I really like 'violate' as it also conveys what I'm doing while giving a warning to the unwary user.

Comment: Violate may also convey exactly how the object will feel about your actions, but personification of bits of memory gets into more subjective territory...

Comment: On second thought, messing with an objects privates against its will and calling it violate might be too edgy for work.

Comment: Aww, come on, you know your coworkers will chuckle next time they update from your VCS.

Comment: +1 for "expose". Not so sure about "violate": the existence of the function violates encapsulation, but the action which the function takes is not, quite, to violate encapsulation. It's a fine distinction, though. The function does violate the C++ standard, so it could be justified anyway on those grounds ;-)

Comment: Bob Martin argues that C had better encapsulation than any OO language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645937/is-encapsulation-possible-without-oop/52727180#52727180

Answer (score 10):

The purpose behind encapsulation is to hide/cover/protect.  The antonym would be reveal/expose/make public.

Comment: Instead of 'make public' maybe I should have included 'publish' or 'publicize'

Answer (score 5):

How about Decapsulation..

Though it aint a computer science term, but in medical science, *Surgical removal of a capsule or enveloping membrane..* Check out [here](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/decapsulation)..

Comment: Scene: (At a crowded bar after work) Dev1 says to Dev2, "What did you do today?" Dev2 replies, "I had to decapsulate someones code." Crowd nearby, thinking it heard "I had to decapitate someone", gives funny looks and backs away.

Answer (score 2):

"Removing/Breaking encapsulation" is about the closest thing I've seen, honestly.

If you think of the word in the English sense, to encapsulate means to enclose within something.  But in the CS sense, there's this concept of protection levels and it looks like you want to imply circumventing the access levels as well, so something like "extraction" doesn't really convey the meaning you're looking for.

But if you just think of it in terms of what the access levels are, it looks like you're making something public so, how about "publicizing"?

Comment: I think expose is much more succinct and from a language perspective I think this should either be "publish" or "publishing" not "publicizing".

Answer (score 2):

This is not such a simple question - Scott Meyers had an interesting article to demonstrate some of the nuances around encapsulation [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401197).

> I'll start with the punchline: If
>   you're writing a function that can be
>   implemented as either a member or as a
>   non-friend non-member, you should
>   prefer to implement it as a non-member
>   function. That decision increases
>   class encapsulation. When you think
>   encapsulation, you should think
>   non-member functions.

Comment: So my question shouldn't be about encapsulation.  I should ask for a verb to describe breaking access-protection-levels-of-an-object.

Comment: Not clear.  If you declare members public you explicitly make them available.  An unwanted `friend` is the best I can think of.  How about `unfriend` or `frenemy` (a noun, but you get the idea)?

Answer (score 0):

How about "Bad Idea"?

Comment: Are you saying that breaking encapsulation for unit tests is a bad idea?  Or that my approach is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

The true antonym of "Encapsulation" is "Global State".

Comment: A global state may well be encapsulated - if you use immutable.js with a single source of truth (central state), you have a global state that is encapsulated (accessed via an interface rater than directly).

Answer (score 0):

The general opposite of *encapsulation* is *coupling* and we often talk about systems that are *tightly coupled* or *loosely coupled.*

The reason you'd want components to be encapsulated is because it makes it easier to reason about how they work.

Take the analogy of trains: the consequence of coupling the railcars is that the driver must consider the characteristics (inertia, length) of the entire train.

Obviously, though, we couple systems because we need them to work together.

#### Inverted encapsulation and data structures

There's another term that I've been digging for, which is how I came across this question, that refers to a non-standard style of data structures.

The standard style of encapsulation is exemplified by [Java's LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html); the actual nodes of the list are designed to be inaccessible to the consumer. The theory is that this is an implementation detail and can change to improve performance, while existing code will continue to run.

Another style is the classic functional cons-list. This is a singly linked list, and the idea is that it's so simple that there's nothing to improve about the data structure, e.g.

```hs
data  [a]  =  [] | a : [a]  deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- Haskellers then work directly with the list
-- There's nothing to hide because it's so simple
typicalHaskell :: [a] -> b
typicalHaskell [] = emptyValue
typicalHaskell h : t = h `doAThing` (typicalHaskell t)
```

That's the [definition from Haskell's standard prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) though the report notes that isn't valid Haskell syntax, and in practice `[a]` is defined in the guts of the compiler.

Then there's what I'm calling an "inverted" data structure, but I'm still looking for the correct term. This is, I think, really the opposite of encapsulation.

A good example of this is Python's [heapq module](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/heapq.html). The data structure here is a binary heap, but there isn't a `Heap` class. Rather, you get a collection of functions that operate on generic Python lists and you're responsible for using those methods correctly to ensure the heap invariants are maintained.

Answer (score -2):

How about "spaghetti"?

Comment: Besides the implied joke, 'spaghetti' is too long to be useful, not to mention a bugger to type.